# Special characters ř and í in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

How do I type the characters ř and í in BibTeX? Some names of people contain them. I've used Detexifier, and it doesn't help much.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) for how to typeset the characters for BibTeX.  It might be best to include them in braces, e.g., `{\v{r}}`, in your `.bib` file.

Comment: You can switch to biblatex/biber to work with such special characters.

Answer (score 6):

In your `.bib` file, you can use `\v{r}` for ř and `\'{i}` for í. Here's a very basic, schematic example:

```
@article{example,
Author = {Example, Autho\v{r}},
Title = {Example T\'{i}tle},
et cetera...
}
```

Here's a [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) to the LaTeX WikiBook that shows you how to write these and other such characters in LaTeX.